# How to make instagram camera type footer in react-native android

Tags: react-native, tabs, scrollview, footer

I have a requirement that the footer in a react-native android application has a swiper to select an entry from (preferably the center one being selected like what is done in instagram app's camera for android, i.e the swiper to select from Normal, Boomerang, Rewind etc). Do we have such control existing that we can reuse? Or what is the way to create a one using scroll view?

Comment: What did you try till now?

Comment: I need two layers of footer. At the bottom there are three options selecting any of them results in updating the entries in the "Instagram camera like swiper" at the top of it. To implement this first I added a scroll view and set of three buttons in the footer. But obviously it is not looking good especially I am not able to locate the center item and mark it as selected. Then I tried using react-native-tab-view but I only need tabbar implementation of it which I am unable to get (would be glad if there is a way to do so. It is similar to my requirement but not exact.

Comment: Update : I came up with a design where I thought I would render 3 buttons at the bottom and clicking any of them would create tabViewAnimated implementation of react-native-tab-view. Then I could call renderFooter to create its  scrollable tab view implementation. This would be similar to my expectation of having two footers with the upper one being scrollable. But I am facing issue while enclosing TabViewAnimated inside a bigger view.  I thought a bigger view would enclose it and my "3 button footer". However enclosing TabViewAnimated inside a view resulted in an empty screen.